# Kerberos API throws error while initializing and renewing credentials

Tags: c, api, runtime-error, kerberos

I'm using kerberos 1.5.0.3 api to develop an authentication system similar to kinit command.

I have two systems, one which has only IPv4 and the second one having both IPv4 and IPv6 (but IPv6 is unconfigured on this client, but configured on server)

This functions works fine on the first machine and doesn't work on the second machine.

The first type of error when kerberos cache is not present is thrown by `krb5_get_init_creds_password: 96C73ADC`

When I manually do kinit and suppose the ticket is valid, then I try stuff out I get the `error 96C73AB9` by the `krb5_get_renewed_creds()` call.

I referred to the error codes here: [Kerberos Error Codes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.euvfa00/euvb3a7092.htm)

Any help is much appreciated even though I'm familiar with Kerberos API, this is my first attempt in writing code which will work on multiple kinds of environments.